# Android media player seekbar

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

I have a service that creates, plays and handles a mediaplayer (just audio), yet I have a seekbar in the main activity that I want to, naturally, show the progress of the audio file and allow the user to seek to various positions.

What I'm having a hell of a time figuring out is: what would be the best or proper way to connect the seekbar in the UI to the mediaplayer in the service?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do this:

1. Bind to service that plays audio. The interface that server returns in `onBind` should have `getCurrentPos()` and `getDuration()` functions.
2. In your Activity's `onCreate` bind to service
3. In your Activity's `onResume` use `Handler`'s `postDelayed` function to start updates.
4. In your Activity's `onPause`  stop all callbacks posted via `postDelayed` function.
5. In runnable that is passed to `postDelayed` run `boundService.getCurrentPos()` and `boundService.getDuration()` and update the seekbar appropriately.

To summarize, you should use service binding and handler for recurring updates.

1. For bound services read ["Bound services"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) documentation (local bounded service should be sufficient in your scenario).
2. How to user `Handler` for periodic updates read this question: [Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay/6242292#6242292)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) to see if it's of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Otto from Square](http://square.github.io/otto/)

You just need to create a class `SeekBarSyncEvent.java`, put the parameters you need in there:

- int progress
- int duration
- boolean fromUser
- whatever you need

Then you can initialize the seekbar from the activity by posting an event from the bus with your `SeekBarSyncEvent` class in the `onPrepared()` method from your service.

Finally create the `@Subscribe` method on your activity so it calls to your `seekBarUpdate()` method.

This should work fine, nice and easy to maintain.