# Update MusicPlayer SeekBar in Service

Tags: android, service, seekbar, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm trying to update music player SeekBar in service, but nothing happens. The service start ok in my activity and bind correctly (because I can use some of the methods in my service and music play fine). Here is my service code:

```
public class MusicPlayerService extends Service {

MediaPlayer myMusicPlayer;
String path;
Intent getMusicId = new Intent();

// Binder given to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    MusicPlayerService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return MusicPlayerService.this;
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myMusicPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),"onCreate()");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onStartCommand()");

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    path = intent.getStringExtra("musicID");

    Log.e("Music path on SD received from intent", path);

    try {
        myMusicPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        myMusicPlayer.setLooping(true);
        myMusicPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myMusicPlayer.start();

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onBind()");

    return mBinder;
}

/** method for clients */
public int getMusicDuration() {
  return myMusicPlayer.getDuration();
}

public int getMusicCurPos(){
    return myMusicPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public void pauseMusic(){
    myMusicPlayer.pause();
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "pauseMusic()");
}

public void playMusic(){
    myMusicPlayer.start();
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "start()");
}
public void stopMusic(){
    myMusicPlayer.stop();
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "stop()");
}
public void seekToPos (int pos){
    myMusicPlayer.seekTo(pos);
}

}
```

Interesting part is, after binding the service to my activity and run it some methods of the service returning null value like `getDuration()` and some of them work find like `onStart()` and `onDestroy()`.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

In your activity you have to check if the service bound because it take a while to do, then use the public methods that it provide like:

```
//Bound Music service and pass the music path
    Intent musicIntent = new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class);
    musicIntent.putExtra("musicID", path); //Put Extra data for music player to play the exact file
    bindService(musicIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); //Bound the Music player service

    //Music Handler for methods
    musicMethodsHandler = new Handler();
    musicRun = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mBound == true){ // Check if service bounded
                if (musicTotTime == null){ // Put data in it one time
                    musicTotTime = myMusicPlayer.getMusicDuration();
                    Log.v("Music Duration of Player in thread", musicTotTime.toString());
                    seekBar.setMax(musicTotTime);
                }
                musicCurTime = myMusicPlayer.getMusicCurPos();
                Log.v("Music Duration of Player in thread", musicCurTime.toString());
                seekBar.setProgress(musicCurTime);
            }else if(mBound == false){ // if service is not bounded log it
                Log.v("Still waiting to bound", Boolean.toString(mBound));
            }
            musicMethodsHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    musicMethodsHandler.postDelayed(musicRun, 1000);


/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        myMusicPlayer = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

and keep in mind that the `onCreate()` method of services run first and one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't update the UI directly from your `Service` class, this is not its responsibility.

In your `Activity` you can run a `CountDownTimer` or similar to periodically poll your `Service` to handle `SeekBar` updates.

If you need to send messages from your Service to your Activity (such as when the track is finished, etc.) you can use a `LocalBroadcastManager`

Some examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256166/833647
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695943/833647

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ken Wolf, but why I can not get the music player duration by calling the service method?

Comment: You say it returns null but do you mean it returns 0?

Comment: In my activity after binding and starting the service when try to get data from service like 'Integer duration = myMediaPlayer.getDuration();' (myMediaPlayer is an object of my service class) it throws a "NullPointerException".

Comment: Make sure you are binding to your service correctly and you only call getDuration after the service is bound. Have a read of this again: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html You don't need onStartCommand to launch a bound service...

Comment: Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE means the service will be created and onCreate will be called the first time its bound to your activity

Comment: @ Ken Wolf, thanks for your advice, review the services and bound services documents, and modify my service class and update it above, in my activity check if the service bound correctly and then use the methods in service to update my UI and work like a charm.