# Android run a Task Periodically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I want to run a method periodically in an android activity which updates a certain field after x seconds. I know it can be done in timerTask but what is the best way to do it? Code samples would be helpful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use `Handler` and its `postDelayed` function. You can find example here: [Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay/6242292#6242292)

Comment: This is not 100% correct. What if I close my activity and app? I want the task to run daily, regardless the app is opened or not (i.e. should be service)

Answer (score 12):

You can use below android classes:

1.Handler

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                  //your code
                   handler.postDelayed(this,20000); 
                    }
                },20000);
```

2.AlarmManager

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


            // Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Yourservice.class);
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(HomeActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 600*1000, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: solution 1 (Handler) doesnt run periodically, but fires only once! (i didnt try solution 2)

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it by CountDownTimer

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

 public void usingCountDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 10000) {

            // This is called after every 10 sec interval. 
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {              
                setUi("Using count down timer");
            }

            public void onFinish() {              
                start();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

and onPause()

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```