# Show progress bar while downloading using download manager

Tags: java, android, download, download-manager, android-download-manager

I am using download manager api for downloading large files, and i achieved it too. But the thing is, the notification of downloading progress is showing in status bar. But i want to show the notification inside the activity using Progress bar. So do anyone have done it, if so plz help me.

```
public class DownloadManagerActivity extends Activity {
private long enqueue;
private DownloadManager dm;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                Query query = new Query();
                query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        String uriString = c
                                .getString(c
                                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                        view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Request request = new Request(
            Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.de/img/lars/LarsVogelArticle7.png"));
    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

}
```

Comment: you can active progress bar in onClick. and dismiss him in onRecieve.

Comment: How can i show the progress bar progressing. Can u post some code, so tat i can get a clear idea. Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android DownloadManager Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824835/android-downloadmanager-progress)

Comment: Already answered this question [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73546957/19881504](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73546957/19881504)

Answer (score 5):

This is the code which i used to show a progess bar in my activity and the download was requested by download manager.

```
final ProgressDialog progressBarDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
progressBarDialog.setTitle("Download App Data, Please Wait");

              progressBarDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressBarDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int whichButton){
                    // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    //       "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            progressBarDialog.setProgress(0);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    boolean downloading = true;

                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    while (downloading) {

                        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                        q.setFilterById(DownloadManagerId); //filter by id which you have receieved when reqesting download from download manager
                        Cursor cursor = manager.query(q);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                        int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                            downloading = false;
                }

                final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        progressBarDialog.setProgress((int) dl_progress);

                    }
                });

                // Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, statusMessage(cursor));
                cursor.close();
            }

        }
    }).start();


  //show the dialog
        progressBarDialog.show();

          }

               }
```

Answer (score 0):

i know its late to answer.
but for the guys come in the future with same query,

The method given by nkalra0123 might not be safe i guess.
There is something called, FileObserver.

[Android DownloadManager Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824835/android-downloadmanager-progress)

This link mentioned above has better solution.

Comment: Thanks, but apparently the given solution stops working after Marshmallow.

Comment: nkarla's solution works fine on Api 27 but not Api 29, when files are very large (e.g 50 MB is fine, but 300 mb is not).