# Android tv DownloadManager with progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-tv, download-manager

I'm struggling with DownloadManager on androidtv, I finally could implement download with the download manager, but I don't know the progress of the download process until it finishes, I would like implement download progress dialog.

I found the following link [DownloadManager with notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569247/progress-bar-of-downloadmanager-with-percentage) but I don't know how to implement it.

Hope you could help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already were able to implement downloading using [**DownloadManager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html), you may try adding a `COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR` constant to get the number of bytes downloaded so far.

You may get ideas on how implementation should be done from the solutions given in the following SO posts:

- [Show Download progress inside activity using DownloadManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795872/show-download-progress-inside-activity-using-downloadmanager)
- [Show Download Manager progress inside activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798569/show-download-manager-progress-inside-activity)

Another option that you may try is to use [**ProgressDialog**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html). As mentioned in the documentation, it functions as

> A dialog showing a progress indicator and an optional text message or view.

To help you with the implementation part, please check the brief but comprehensive solution given in this SO post - [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660).