# DownloadManager with custom notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-download-manager, download-manager

I'm hitting a wall right now, I'd like to download a file with the `DownloadManager` and it's working. However I'd like to custom that notification with for example instead of having the progress in percent on the right, I'd like to display: `DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR / DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES` and also add a button when the download is done (but for that I know there is a receiver when download completed)

So far my code looks like that:

```java
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(mpopup.apk));
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Channel_ID")
                                        .setOngoing(true)
                                        .setAutoCancel(false)
                                        .setContentTitle("DOWNLOAD FILE")
                                        .setContentText("Downloading 0MB/100MB")
                                        .setProgress(100,0,false);


request.setTitle("DOWNLOAD TITLE");
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

How do I do to update the progress bar and the text in my notification ? While it's downloading

I've tried : [DownloadManager notification displays no percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989922/downloadmanager-notification-displays-no-percentage) but it's not working and only display the log once completely downloaded

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't update the Notification because you have no control over it.

The only solution is to manage the download yourself and thus the notification with it.