# Xamarin Android C# resume download after disconnect

Tags: c#, android, amazon-s3, xamarin.android

I am facing a problem where a user is downloading a large file (roughly 1.5GB) and if the connection dropped, the user needs to restart downloading from beginning.

What can I do in Xamarin Android C# to implement resume download? The file will be hosted on Amazon S3.

Any help will be fantastic!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use [DownloadManager](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.DownloadManager/) - it

> will conduct the download in the background, taking care of HTTP
>   interactions and retrying downloads after failures or across
>   connectivity changes and system reboots.

```
var manager = DownloadManager.FromContext(this); 
var request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.Parse(uri));
long downloadId = manager.Enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm looking for solution within application. I want to visually show status as part of the interface. Any suggestion on what I can do to have similar functionality as download manager but inside my application? Thanks!

Comment: @WorldWind You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002259/6950238) approach to get information about start/resume/progress.