# Android R: Create file in Download directory

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

Starting from the answer to this question

[Write to Download Folder like Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103133/how-to-directly-download-a-file-to-download-directory-on-android-q-android-10)

I am trying to write a file to the download directory.
This is the code I use.

```
 File downloadedFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), FILE_NAME);
 ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, downloadedFile.getName());
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,
                contentResolver.getType(Uri.fromFile(downloadedFile)));
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, downloadedFile.length());
        uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
    } else {
      //omitted
    }

    try(
            OutputStream outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "w");
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream
                    = new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(downloadedFile.getAbsoluteFile()))
    ) {
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(buff)) > 0)
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, len);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        //omitted        
}
```

On android Q it works perfectly. On android R it says it has completed but in fact it is not in the folder.
Where am I wrong? Thank you

Comment: You forgot outputStream.close();.

Comment: Look for IS_PENDING.

Comment: `On android R it says it has completed` There is nothing in your code that does so.

Comment: did you add     <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >

Comment: I used try-with-resources instead of using close.
IS_PENDING is not necessary, in Q works.
I say it complete because not thrown exception
I don't want to use requestLegacyExternalStorage

Comment: After several searches I found the file, but it is not saved in the download directory, but in the Music directory. The file has an .m3u extension. How is it possible?