# How do I code a static handler due to: This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur

Tags: android

In my project it keeps crashing due to the VM budget being exceed. The pictures that I am using are all very small but supposedly they keep filling up the VM. I was working through eclipse and notice 2 instances where it gave me the following errors.

This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur (com.quickreaction.BT_screen_menuButtons.2) BT_screen_menuButtons.java /BT_activity_root/src/com/quickreaction line 1091   Android Lint Problem

When I follow the two links this is the source code that it brings me too.

```
Handler downloadScreenDataHandler = new Handler(){ 
@Override public void handleMessage(Message msg){ 
if(JSONData.length() < 1){ 
hideProgress(); 
showAlert(getString(R.string.errorTitle), getString(R.string.errorDownloadingData)); 
}else{ 
parseScreenData(JSONData); 
} 
} 
};
```

And..

```
private Handler buttonImageHandler = new Handler() { 
public void handleMessage(Message msg){ 
//BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":buttonImageHandler setting background image for        button."); 
//msg.what will equal the index of the button images array... 

//set the drawable... 
Drawable d; 

//we may need to round the image... 
if(buttonCornerRadius > 0){ 
d = buttonImages.get(msg.what); 

//we have a drawable, our rounding method needs a bitmap... 
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap(); 
b = BT_viewUtilities.getRoundedImage(b, buttonCornerRadius); 

//convert it back to a drawable... 
d = new BitmapDrawable(b); 

}else{ 
d = buttonImages.get(msg.what); 
} 
buttonSquares.get(msg.what).setBackgroundDrawable(d); 
buttonSquares.get(msg.what).invalidate();
```

} 
   };

I have been reading on stack overflow about making the handler static or weak but don't know how. Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

These lint messages about making `Handler` `weak` or `static` can usually be ignored. If you are creating a `Handler` and storing a reference to it in your activity, then when your activity is destroyed the `Handler` will also go away. There is no leak here. The only time there could be a leak is if, when your activity goes away, there is still a message in the message queue for that `Handler`. However, this is usually not the case.

After looking at your code, I conclude that you can't make your `Handler` `static` (ie: and inner class) because it needs a reference to its outer class (the activity). Also, making it a stand-alone class (like in CommonsWare's answer) won't help either because you will need to pass a reference to your activity when you instantiate the stand-alone class, so this won't help solve the "leak" either (if there really is one). It might get the stupid LINT warning to go away though :-)

If you are having memory issues, you should use a heap analyzer like JHAT or MAT and actually see what objects you've got in memory before paying attention to these silly lint warnings.

See also [This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur: final Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507208/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-final-handler?rq=1) and [This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur: IncomingHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an instance of an anonymous inner class (e.g., `new Handler() {}`), create a static inner class (e.g., `static class MyHandler extends Handler`) or a regular Java class (`class MyHandler extends Handler`) and use it instead.

Comment: Does adding either of those codes require more coding to set up the MyHandler?

Comment: @user2543132: You would just call `new MyHandler()` to create an instance of your `MyHandler` class.