# How to repeat a task after a fixed amount of time in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to repeatedly call a method after every 5-seconds and whenever I wish to to stop the repeated call of the method I may stop or restart the repeated call of the method.

Here is some sample code that whats really I want to implement. Please help me in this respect I would be very thankful to you.

```
private int m_interval = 5000; // 5 seconds by default, can be changed later
private Handler m_handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
  ...
  m_handler = new Handler();
}

Runnable m_statusChecker = new Runnable()
{
     @Override 
     public void run() {
          updateStatus(); //this function can change value of m_interval.
          m_handler.postDelayed(m_statusChecker, m_interval);
     }
};

public void startRepeatingTask()
{
    m_statusChecker.run(); 
}

public void stopRepeatingTask()
{
    m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_statusChecker);
}
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14377875/28557 and http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks/

Comment: I think its easy to use CountDownTimer. See here for tutorial  http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-count-down-timer.html

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Set repeated task using this:

```
//Declare the timer
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
    }

},
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
1000);
```

and if you wanted to cancel the task simply call `t.cancel()` here `t` is your `Timer` object

and you can also check comment placed below your answer they have given brief information about that.

Comment: After the first iteration, I'm getting "Called from wrong thread exception"

Comment: For Android a Handler is preferable to a Timer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330355/timertask-or-handler

Answer (score 7):

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in the `onCreate()` method. Its `postDelayed()` method causes the `Runnable` to be added to the message queue and to be run after the specified amount of time elapses (that is 0 in given example). Then this will queue itself after fixed rate of time (1000 milliseconds in this example).

Refer this code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    android.os.Handler customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //write here whaterver you want to repeat
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: Suppose my scheduled time is every 10 minutes and my phone goes to Doze mode or the ideal mode or I lock the device. Will the handler still call my method after 10 minutes? Currently, it is not working. Handler only getting called when my Application Resumes.

Comment: @Sniper you would need to use Alarm Manager for the function to be called when the app isn't running https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 5):

use TimerTask to call after specific time interval

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(),1, TimeInterval);
```

and

```
  class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() 
           {        
            // do stufff
           }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it in Android's way with the help of [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Declare a Handler which [does not leak Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278875/handlers-and-memory-leaks-in-android)

```
/**
     * Instances of static inner classes do not hold an implicit
     * reference to their outer class.
     */
    private static class NonLeakyHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<FlashActivity> mActivity;

        public NonLeakyHandler(FlashActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<FlashActivity>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            FlashActivity activity = mActivity.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Declare a runnable which handle your task

```
   private Runnable repeatativeTaskRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

         //DO YOUR THINGS
        }
    };
```

Initialize handler object in your Activity/Fragment

```
//Task Handler
private Handler taskHandler = new NonLeakyHandler(FlashActivity.this);
```

Repeat task after fix time interval

> taskHandler.postDelayed(repeatativeTaskRunnable , DELAY_MILLIS);

Stop repetition

> taskHandler .removeCallbacks(repeatativeTaskRunnable );

Comment: Suppose my scheduled time is every 10 minutes and my phone goes to Doze mode or the ideal mode or I lock the device. Will the handler still call my method after 10 minutes? Currently, it is not working. Handler only getting called when my Application Resumes

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this code inside the activity you want to call every 5 seconds

```
final Runnable tarea = new Runnable() {   public void run() {
hola_mundo();//the operation that you want to perform }}; 
ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarea, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```