# Timertask or Handler

Tags: android, performance, timer, handler, timertask

Let's say that I want to perform some action every 10 seconds and it doesn't necessarily need to update the view.

The question is: is it better (I mean more efficient and effective) to use timer with timertask like here:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               <some task>
            }
        });
    }
};
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timertask, 0, 15000);
}
```

or just a handler with postdelayed

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        <some task>
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 15000);
```

Also I would be grateful if you could explain when to use which approach and why one of them is more efficient than another (if it actually is).

Comment: I've read many posts about irregular behavior of TimerTasks. My advice would be steer clear of them and use the handler / postDelayed approach.

Comment: I'd prefer the Handler-postDelay method - you have more control and you schedule it from the inside

Comment: Here is a great source for [Timer vs. Handler](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/12/handler-vs-timer-fixed-period-execution.html)

Comment: TimerTask is a background-task, so you can not update UI. Just saying...

Comment: For the people reading this: @Yousha Aleayoub of course you can using the Handler.

Comment: @David I'm talking about `TimerTask` not `Handler`.

Comment: @Yousha Aleayoub I know, but if you want something to run in the backgronud you will use TimerTask and then to update the UI from inside the TimerTask you will use the handler to do this. With Handler you run directly all in the UI Thread which will not always be what you want.

Answer (score 113):

**`Handler` is better than `TimerTask`.**

The Java `TimerTask` and the Android `Handler` both allow you to schedule delayed and repeated tasks on background threads. However, the literature overwhelmingly recommends using `Handler` over `TimerTask` in Android (see [here](http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/), [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks), [here](https://cemremengu.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/android-timertimertask-out-handler-in/), [here](http://saeedsiam.blogspot.com/2009/03/timer-in-android-better-way.html), [here](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/12/handler-vs-timer-fixed-period-execution.html), and [here](http://baiduhix.blogspot.com/2016/02/handler-vs-asynctask-handler-vs-timer.html)).

Some of reported problems with TimerTask include:

- Can't update the UI thread
- Memory leaks
- Unreliable (doesn't always work)
- Long running tasks can interfere with the next scheduled event

**Example**

The best source for all kinds of Android examples that I have seen is at [Codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks). Here is a `Handler` example from there for a repeating task.

```
// Create the Handler object (on the main thread by default)
Handler handler = new Handler();
// Define the code block to be executed
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Do something here on the main thread
      Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread");
      // Repeat this the same runnable code block again another 2 seconds
      handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 2000);
    }
};
// Start the initial runnable task by posting through the handler
handler.post(runnableCode);
```

**Related**

- [Handler vs Timer : fixed-period execution and fixed-rate execution android development](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/12/handler-vs-timer-fixed-period-execution.html)

Comment: @Reek No, GC should take care of it. But you need to take care of the runnable posted for delayed execution. In the example above the runnable used is an inner class instance so holds an implicit reference to the containing class (which might be an activity). The runnable will stay in the handler's associated looper's message queue until its next execution time which may be after the context is invalid and might leak the containing class instance. You can clear such references by using `mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnableCode)` at the appropriate time (e.g. `onStop()` for an activity).

Comment: Best way of presenting references ever!!! (see here, here, here, here, here, and here).

Comment: and what if I want to use that inside a ViewModel? isn't against the ideal of not having android things there?

Comment: @desgraci, I haven't used a ViewModel, but from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel) I only see that it says the ViewModel shouldn't access the view hierarchy or contain a reference to the Activity or Fragment. I don't see anything forbidding having "Android things" in general.

Comment: As of today those references are to me outdated and not informative enough to be taken into consideration. Those 4 listed drawbacks are only real if you programm your code badly. TimerTasks are still a very good choice if you want to periodically run something in the background and eventually run something on the UIThread if some condition applies.

Comment: "But you need to take care of the runnable posted for delayed execution" to solve this you need to create a static class thtat implements Runnable and save a weekReference of the containing class (perhaps the actiivity), doing so you would solve the problem of eventual memory leak.

Comment: @David, thanks for your comments. Is there any reason you wouldn't use a `Handler`? If `TimerTask` is susceptible to people who program badly, then I still prefer to avoid it. I tend to program badly on occasion.

Comment: Handler is also equally susceptible being able to produce memory leaks on Android if not programmed carefully enough. I don't think one is better than the other, it depends on the case.

Comment: Android Studio reports that Variable 'runnableCode' might not have been initialized.

Comment: Can you clarify how TimerTask is `Unreliable (doesn't always work)`? I clicked on all the links and I couldn't find one that actually clarified this. The first link also appears to be dead. Additionally, how up-to-date is this information? What if you only support Android 7+?

Comment: @Awesome-o, Good question. It's been so long since I've written this that I don't remember myself. If you read all of those links and there is nothing to support "Unreliable (doesn't always work)" then maybe this should be removed from the list. Feel free to edit it out of my answer (along with the dead link). As far as how up-to-date this answer is, I would still assume that an Android class would be better than a plain Java one, but I'm focusing on Flutter now so I've fallen behind in my current Android knowledge.

Answer (score 19):

> There are some disadvantages of using Timer
>
> It creates only single thread to execute the tasks and if a task takes
>   too long to run, other tasks suffer. It does not handle exceptions
>   thrown by tasks and thread just terminates, which affects other
>   scheduled tasks and they are never run

Copied from:

[TimerTask vs Thread.sleep vs Handler postDelayed - most accurate to call function every N milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605403/timertask-vs-thread-sleep-vs-handler-postdelayed-most-accurate-to-call-functio)

Comment: so what about for a one-shot task?  it sounds like maybe Timer is better for that because you don't have the overhead of the message queue?

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 11):

**Kotlin version of accepted answer:**

```
// execute on the main thread, empty constructor is deprecated
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

val runnableCode = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread")
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000)
    }
}

// or shorter using a lambda function
val runnableCode = Runnable {
    Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread")
    handler.postDelayed(this, 2000)
}

handler.post(runnableCode)
```

Comment: Would be helpful to add an example of a Handler running on a separate thread, for tasks that do not need to update ui.