# Android multiple posts with delay

Tags: android, timer, handler, postdelayed

I have a set of instructions that needs to be executed **repeatedly**.
The repeat delay is **variable** (the delay is taken from a file).

The repeat time must be very **precise** (milliseconds precision).

I have tried to use a Handler with postDelayed but the accuracy is lost in time. This happens because the repeat frequency is more than 10 times/second.

Any idea is more than welcomed!

Here is the Handler example:

```
new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {              
         mHandler.postDelayed(this, delay);               
         barometerResult.gotBarometer(barometerValueModelList.get(i).getBarometerValue());             
       }
    }.run();
```

Comment: Post your code using Handler.
Is this code being executed while your app is active, or is it maybe in the background with the posibility of calling your code while device is inactive?

Comment: Is your handler updating a view? I'm guessing this is run on main thread, right?

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion ?

Comment: This handler will not update a view. It doesn't run on the main thread. It will only send a value in order to be processed.(in this case is sends the altitude from barometer sensor).

Comment: MinSdkVersion 19

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea using Handler, it runs in the UI thread with many other things to do in the queue, so that's not guarantee your runnable code would be executed so precisely.

If your work in the Runnable is just some logic task not involved in update UI.Consider using a Timer to do that but be ware that it will run on a separated thread.

Comment: Handler can be used without it being on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: As I understand, the Handler is more precise than the java Timer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330355/timertask-or-handler