# How to call a function after delay in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

As the title, is there any way to call a function after delay (1 second for example) in `Kotlin`?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You can use [Schedule](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.-timer/schedule.html)

```
inline fun Timer.schedule(
    delay: Long, 
    crossinline action: TimerTask.() -> Unit
): TimerTask (source)
```

example (thanks @Nguyen Minh Binh - found it here: http://jamie.mccrindle.org/2013/02/exploring-kotlin-standard-library-part-3.html)

```
import java.util.Timer
import kotlin.concurrent.schedule

Timer("SettingUp", false).schedule(500) { 
   doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Super easy. Found an example here http://jamie.mccrindle.org/2013/02/exploring-kotlin-standard-library-part-3.html
`Timer("SettingUp", false).schedule(500) { doSomething() }`

Comment: It does compile, if you add these two imports:
import java.util.Timer and import kotlin.concurrent.schedule

Comment: @Matias Elorriaga, for me, putting this on a new brand file doesn't compile, even adding the imports Customizer said

Comment: you don't need to put it on a file, that method is part of stdlib, follow the link in the first line of the answer,

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga I think the people want an example! :)

Comment: for those that would like to have it run at an interval: timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(0, inactivityHeartbeat) { //.... do stuff}

Comment: I originally thought this wouldn't compile even after importing `kotlin.concurrent.schedule`, because Kotlin merely complained of a signature mismatch, but then I realized I was trying to pass an Int instead of a Long. It compiled after correcting that.

Comment: Can someone show this as an example.  Cut and pasted this and it does not compile had both imports too.  Says the schedule needs a body on the inline function

Comment: May I know how to cancel the timer?

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't compile like many of the comments have already indicated.

Comment: @AndroidDev is part of the standard library, you don’t need to compile, just add the import..

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - this code compiles fine on Kotlin 1.3.50. What's your error msg? You might have faced my initial problem: make sure the numeric value passed in (500) is a Long and not Int. You'll get a compile error if you do something like: Timer("SettingUp", false).schedule(500+x) {} where "x" is an Int you declared elsewhere. Declare x as a Long and you'll be fine, e.g., val x = 25L

Comment: that work great! Following question is how to insert my class scope inside of this. AKA  replace ` doSomething()` with `this.myFunc()`?

Comment: Timer creates a new tread, keep this in mind.

Answer (score 265):

There is also an option to use `Handler -> postDelayed`

```
 Handler().postDelayed({
                    //doSomethingHere()
                }, 1000)
```

Comment: Please add that it is only available on android, since the question asks for a general kotlin method (although it does have the Android tag)

Comment: It's not constructive from your side. As a result when users will search android tag might think that this is wrong answer.

Comment: For Android, it's better to use Handler than Timer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330355/timertask-or-handler

Comment: I think, you should add a code for removing handlers after activity/fragment finish.

Comment: This will not run on the UI thread if you intended on doing that.

Comment: In Android, Handler is deprecated. any alternative?

Comment: I think for Android and Kotlin ist Coroutines the best alternative.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html

Comment: @leeCoder Use: `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` instead. `Handler()` call without looper is deprecated, but if you specify the Looper yourself it is all good.

Comment: `Handler.postDelayed` is Deprecated, you should use  `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed`

Comment: What about using Kotlin delay?

Answer (score 239):

### Many Ways

#### 1. Using `Handler` class

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    TODO("Do something")
    }, 2000)
```

#### 2. Using `Timer` class

```
Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        TODO("Do something")
    }
}, 2000)

// Shorter

Timer().schedule(timerTask {
    TODO("Do something")
}, 2000)


// Shortest

Timer().schedule(2000) {
    TODO("Do something")
}
```

#### 3. Using `Executors` class

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule({
    TODO("Do something")
}, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Comment: and what do you think is the best solution here?

Comment: Probably the first one using a Handler. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40339630/1159930

Comment: Can we do it synchronously , Handler is in Android package I believe. Is there any other way

Comment: @AkshayHazari See his answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801912/6891563

Comment: Just to follow up on the comment regarding Handler().postDelayed being the best solution... that's deprecated now (at least in Android) and suggests Executors, so at least for Android I'd say that's the "best solution" (though Timer is also simple and straightforward)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851895/6576302

Answer (score 63):

You could `launch` a coroutine, `delay` it and then call the function:

```
 /*GlobalScope.*/launch {
   delay(1000)
   yourFn()
 }
```

If you are outside of a class or object prepend `GlobalScope` to let the coroutine run there, otherwise it is recommended to implement the [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/) in the surrounding class, which allows to cancel all coroutines associated to that scope if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Strange, that coroutines were mentioned only in 2018.

Comment: @coolMind they are stable since a few months, so they are quite new ...

Comment: Yes, from October-November, but existed before.

Comment: CAUTION: This approach counts against the dispatcher's available parallelism even while the coroutine is suspended with `delay()`. I think using a Timer is a much safer Kotlin-generic option.

Answer (score 54):

You have to import the following two libraries:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.concurrent.schedule
```

and after that use it in this way:

```
Timer().schedule(10000){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 31):

```
val timer = Timer()
timer.schedule(timerTask { nextScreen() }, 3000)
```

Comment: Can you please explain me why I there's need to write "timerTask" instead of just braces?

Comment: I think you do. `Timer.schedule()` expects a `TimerTask` as it's first argument. `kotlin.concurrent.timerTask()` wraps the given lambda in a `TimerTask` instance. See here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/timer-task.html

Comment: Also, the given example can be condensed to one line if the `Timer` object isn't going to be used more than once, e.g., `Timer().schedule(timerTask { ... }, 3000)`. A more Kotlin-friendly option is available too; see jonguer's answer.

Answer (score 21):

If you are in a fragment with viewModel scope you can use Kotlin coroutines:

```
    myViewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
        delay(2000)
        // DoSomething()
    }
```

Comment: what dispatcher do you suggest to use here if the task does not do any api request?

Comment: @paxcow it depends, if its just for a testing use case you can use the Main. But in any other case, I'd always use IO because you are delaying a task, similar what we do with an API request.

Comment: Only specify dispatchers when you are calling blocking code, or when you're calling main-only code (like interacting with Views or LiveData and you aren't already on Dispatchers.Main).

Answer (score 20):

If you're using more recent Android APIs the Handler empty constructor has been deprecated and you should include a Looper. You can easily get one through `Looper.getMainLooper()`.

```
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        //Your code
    }, 2000) //millis
```

Answer (score 12):

A simple example to show a toast after **3 seconds** :

```
fun onBtnClick() {
    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed({ showToast() }, 3000)
}

fun showToast(){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Its toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: can i cancel the call?

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for generic usage, here is my suggestion:

Create a class named as `Run`:

```
class Run {
    companion object {
        fun after(delay: Long, process: () -> Unit) {
            Handler().postDelayed({
                process()
            }, delay)
        }
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
Run.after(1000, {
    // print something useful etc.
})
```

Comment: You can simplify this as extension fucntion

Comment: @Ogulcan, more kotlinic lamda `Run.after(1000) { toRun() }`. Am I correct

Answer (score 4):

i suggest to use kotlin coroutine and if you want to cancel it. its simple and light weight.

```
fun repeatFun(): Job {
    return coroutineScope.launch {  
        while(isActive) {
            //do your work here
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
}

//start the loop
val repeatFun = repeatRequest()

//Cancel the loop
repeatFun.cancel()
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommended using **SingleThread** because you do not have to kill it after using. Also, "*stop*()" method is deprecated in Kotlin language.

```
private fun mDoThisJob(){

    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate({
        //TODO: You can write your periodical job here..!

    }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

Moreover, you can use it for periodical job. It is very useful. If you would like to do job for each second, you can set because parameters of it:

> Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit);

TimeUnit values are: NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS, MILLISECONDS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS.

Comment: You still have to kill it when you navigate away from whatever is using it, or you'll leak the references it is capturing.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function(s):

```kotlin
fun <T> delayedAsyncTask(delayMs: Long = 0, task: () -> T): ScheduledFuture<T> {
    return Executors
        .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
        .schedule(Callable<T> { task() }, delayMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}

fun <T> asyncTask(task: () -> T) = delayedAsyncTask(0, task)
```

Here's a unit test for the delayed function. Use of the returned future is optional of course.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `delayed task work correctly`() {
        val future = delayedAsyncTask(1000) {
            "lambda returns hello world"
        }
        assertEquals(false, future.isDone)
        Thread.sleep(1100)
        assertEquals(true, future.isDone)
        assertEquals("lambda returns hello world", future.get())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to create a redundant job other than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69180900/7873768); that does not require the function to be suspend.

```
   val repeatableJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        while (true) {
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
```

Cancel when you are done -
`repeatableJob.cancel()`

Comment: Careful using an unmanaged CoroutineScope--this coroutine will leak memory and threads if not manually cancelled when the objects it captures references to become obsolete. It's the same issue GlobalScope has. [More info here](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc)

Comment: I do have suggested cancelling task above and the article just suggests the same manual cancellation or using withContext with suspend function, either way its not a difference with one exception where withContext blocks failure will result in cancellation of all coroutines associated with it, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56866621/7873768)

Comment: Yes, you recommended cancelling the Job. I was just adding a point, since using `CoroutineScope().launch` is a common anti-pattern some newbies use to avoid the GlobalScope warning without understanding the warning and when it is appropriate to use GlobalScope.

Comment: fair point - there is no lifecycle owner in my way of creating coroutine. So yes manual clean up is mandatory. I do strictly use lifecycles events to cancel or recreate and also sometimes to manually cancel it and re-create when needed this way i have full control for adhoc scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

if you are call function in UI.

```
Timer().schedule(1000) {
  activity?.runOnUiThread {
    doSomething()
  }
}
```