# Accurate time in (at least) microseconds since epoch in Java

Tags: java, time, kotlin

I would like to get the current time in microseconds since epoch with as much accuracy as possible, and in a monotonic way.

Does anyone have experience with that? I tried the following two approaches, but the first one is inaccurate and not monotonic, and I'm not sure the second won't have a weird behaviour when time jumps from one millisecond to the next.

(I'm working with Kotlin so I'm open to any kind of Java solution)

```
fun nowInMicrosSinceEpoch() : Long {
    val now = Instant.now()
    return now.toEpochMilli() * 1000L + (now.getNano().toLong() / 1000L)
}
```

```
fun nowInMicrosSinceEpoch() : Long {
    return (System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000L) + (System.nanoTime() % 1_000_000L / 1000L)
}
```

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` has nothing whatsoever to do with real time, so do not use that.

Comment: I know it's meant to measure intervals... Is there a way to get something accurate?

Comment: The only way to absolute guarantee accurate, monotonic time is to call a time service. See [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) (Network Time Protocol). Anything else depends on the computers time, and it can be changed, so no guarantee of monotonic values. Java's time values all derived from the computer time.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I do not need anything perfectly exact, only something monotonic and close to the real "absolute" time given by an atomic clock. This code will always run on the same server, so I only need the data it writes to be consistent.

Comment: Added new duplicate link saying that you get nano-second precision from `Instant.now()` if you use Java 9 (or later), so **use Java 11**, since Java 9 and 10 are both EOL already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228304/delay-accuracy-issues-weird-behavior-of-job-scheduler - Instant.now() is not monotonic...

Comment: It is as monotonic as the `Clock` it is using, and since they totally re-implemented the `Clock` in Java 9 for extended precision ([JDK-8068730](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730)), how would you know from some obscure, unverified test done in Java 8?

Comment: Let me re-phrase "obscure, unverified test" to "invalid code". Added answer to that question explaining why. Even in Java 8, `Instant.now()` *is* monotonic.