# Kotlin: call a function every second

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a simple countdown for my game, when the game starts I want this function to be called every second:

```
fun minusOneSecond(){
  if secondsLeft > 0{
     secondsLeft -= 1
     seconds_thegame.text = secondsLeft.toString()
  }
}
```

I tried this:

```
var secondsLeft = 15

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
   object : TimerTask() {

      override fun run() {
         minusOneSecond()
      }

    },0, 1000
)   // 1000 Millisecond  = 1 second
```

**But the app unfortunately stops, the 2nd time the run function is called**

I just started with android development and Kotlin 3 weeks ago and so far I understand the most out of it.

With swift in Xcode I use this line and I thought something similar would work with Kotlin

```
setTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(minusOneSecond), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function after delay in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348623/how-to-call-a-function-after-delay-in-kotlin)

Comment: The runOnUiThread is necessary because the UI can only be manipulated from a UI thread, and the callback happens in a temporary background thread.

Comment: What about using an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)) ? With a background task composed of a loop, that wait a sec, then update progress. And a onProgressUpdate() method that update your UI.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Problem:** [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) class uses a background thread with a queue to queue and execute all tasks sequentially. From your code, because you update UI (changing TextView content in `minusOneSecond` function). That why the app throws the following exception and make your app crash.

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

**Solution:** There are many ways to achieve your task, but I prefer using **post()** and **postDelayed()** method from [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) class. Because it's simple and easy to understand.

```
val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

mainHandler.post(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        minusOneSecond()
        mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }
})
```

**Update:** From author's comment about how to pause/resume the task from Handler. Here is an example.

```
class MainActivityKt : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mainHandler: Handler

    private val updateTextTask = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            minusOneSecond()
            mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // Your logic code
        ...
        mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mainHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTextTask)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mainHandler.post(updateTextTask)
    }

    fun minusOneSecond() {
        if secondsLeft > 0 {
            secondsLeft -= 1
            seconds_thegame.text = secondsLeft.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

I am using this code to update a clock every minute

```
 fixedRateTimer("timer", false, 0L, 60 * 1000) {
     this@FullscreenActivity.runOnUiThread {
         tvTime.text = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM - HH:mm", Locale.US).format(Date())
     }
 }
```

so you have to run it with paratemer `1000` instead of `60*1000`

Answer (score 10):

please use

```
inline fun Timer.schedule(
    time: Date, 
    period: Long, 
    crossinline action: TimerTask.() -> Unit
): TimerTask
```

reference: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.-timer/schedule.html

Comment: Simple, efficient, and from the docs. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
val timer = object: CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        // do something
    }
    override fun onFinish() {
        // do something
    }
}
timer.start()
```

You can also use CountDownTimer for this purpose. As this takes two parameters (the total time and the interval time)

Plus it also provides an on finish method to perform any task when the total time is finished.

Comment: This is not good. It limits you to having to know the maximum amount of time in advance and will terminate when that time is reached.

Answer (score 4):

> I am calling my function every second like this

```
val handler = Handler()
  handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
      override fun run() {
            //Call your function here
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)//1 sec delay
        }
}, 0)
```

Comment: Why put 0  over there?

Answer (score 3):

My solution

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while(isActive) {
                when(val response = repository.getApi()) {
                    is NetworkState.Success -> {
                        getAllData.postValue(response.data)
                    }
                    is NetworkState.Error -> this@MainViewModel.isActive = false
                }

                delay(API_CALL_DELAY)
            }
        }
```

Comment: This does not execute every second. It executes every second plus the amount of time to perform the code inside the while statement.

Answer (score 3):

if you use any background task or background service try this code

```
val timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate({
            Log.d("RUNNING ","Thread")
        },0,10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

if you work with UI thers like update UI layout try this code

```
val timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate({
            Log.d("RUNNING ","BACKGROUN Thread")
            runOnUiThread {
                Log.d("RUNNING ","Update UI Thread")
                btnUpdate.setText(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
            }
        },0,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isActionAchieved = false
var secondsPassed = 0

fun cDTimer(){
    if (!isActionAchieved && secondsPassed < 10){  // repeat check if Action NOT Achieved for max of 10 seconds 
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            repeatThisFunction()
            repeater()
            secondsPassed++
        }, 1000) //one second till next execution
    }
}

fun repeater(){
    cDTimer()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm using recursion with Coroutine its very simple

```
  private fun loop() {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        delay(5000)
        CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
            ManagerToWorker()
            loop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that grow the stack until overflow ?

Comment: @Antzi it will overflow, but the stack is large enough that the commenter couldn't see it with 5 second delay.

Comment: Recursion often leads to unexpected stack overflows.  While this solution may "work" in limited situations, it will eventually crash (perhaps after many hours or even days given the 5000ms delay).

Comment: As I think about this further, this may not technically cause a stack overflow, since each call to CoroutineScope(Main).launch would create a separate runnable.  However, it would still lead to a memory leak in most cases, since Stacktrace Recovery would remember each call.  (If ManagerToWorker() threw an exception, the stack trace could be enormous!)
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/topics/debugging.md#stacktrace-recovery