# coroutine scope inside withcontext and only withContext usage

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

you can see below two methods, the first one using withContext and coroutineScope and second function using only coroutine Scope. What if it will used only withContext? or only coroutine scope? Why both need to be used?

```
override suspend fun deleteAllTasks() {
        withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            coroutineScope {
                launch { tasksRemoteDataSource.deleteAllTasks() }
                launch { tasksLocalDataSource.deleteAllTasks() }
            }
        }
    }

override suspend fun deleteTask(taskId: String) {
    coroutineScope {
        launch { tasksRemoteDataSource.deleteTask(taskId) }
        launch { tasksLocalDataSource.deleteTask(taskId) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin coroutines, what is the difference between coroutineScope and withContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858624/kotlin-coroutines-what-is-the-difference-between-coroutinescope-and-withcontext)

Comment: but they explained as separated functions , here the cases are what if using both

Answer (score 0):

In that case there is no need for `coroutineScope` inside `withContext`, since `withContext` does this for you already.

There are situations where using `coroutineScope` inside `withContext` could be useful.

```kotlin
withContext(ioDispatcher) {
    coroutineScope {
        launch { tasksRemoteDataSource.deleteAllTasks() }
        launch { tasksLocalDataSource.deleteAllTasks() }
    }
    coroutineScope {
        launch { tasksRemoteDataSource.deleteAllTasks() }
        launch { tasksLocalDataSource.deleteAllTasks() }
    }
}
```

Here the `coroutineScope`s are use for parallel decomposition and to delineate the set of concurrent tasks.