# Kotlin difference between CoroutineScope and withContext

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

To change the thread in a function I use either CoroutineScope or withContext. I don't know's the difference, but with CourineScope I can also use a handler.

Examples:

```
private fun removeViews(){
    CoroutineScope(Main).launch(handler){
        gridRoot.removeAllViews()
    }
}

private suspend fun removeViews(){
    withContext(Main){
        gridRoot.removeAllViews()
    }
}
```

I call this function from a coroutine that works on background thread (IO). Is any more appropriate than the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin coroutines, what is the difference between coroutineScope and withContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858624/kotlin-coroutines-what-is-the-difference-between-coroutinescope-and-withcontext)

Answer (score 3):

These two are actually radically different and you just happen to have a use case where you don't experience the difference:

> `CoroutineScope(Main).launch(handler){`

This launches a concurrent coroutine that goes on independently.

> `withContext(Main){`

This is a function that completes only when the code inside it completes, and returns its result. This is the way you *should* be doing it.

The first approach, with `CoroutineScope`, has another deficiency in that it circumvents structured concurrency. You create an ad-hoc coroutine scope that has no parent and thus won't be automatically cleaned up if it takes a longer time to complete and your GUI is dropped (user navigates away from the current Activity).

You should actually never use the `CoroutineScope(Main)` idiom, I don't think there's a single instance where it would be appropriate. If you explicitly want to avoid structured concurrency, it is still better and cleaner to write

```
GlobalScope.launch(Main + handler) {
```

and has pretty much the same effect.

If you want a concurrent coroutine that fits into structured concurrency, use

```
fun CoroutineScope.removeViews() {
    launch {
        gridRoot.removeAllViews()
    }
}
```

Note I removed the `handler` argument, a child coroutine ignores it because it forwards any failures to its parent coroutine, which is exactly what you want. The parent coroutine should have an exception handler installed.

Comment: What if I want to call a suspend function from a different file like DialogFragment? It needs to be called from a Coroutine, so I should use GlobalScope.launch(Main + handler) or?

Comment: That `DialogFragment` should be its scope, most probably. It should either implement `CoroutineScope` or have a `val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope` inside. `ViewModel`, for example, already has that [integrated.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) And then you call `viewModelScope.launch { ... }`.

Comment: BTW there's convenience for implementing `CoroutineScope` on Android: `class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment, CoroutineScope by MainScope {`

Answer (score 2):

Technically both are same but when it comes to use case both are different and has big impact on the different use cases so be careful while using them
**Coroutine Scope:**
CoroutineScope is a starting Point of Coroutine. CoroutineScope can have more than one coroutine within itself, which makes coroutine hierarchy.
Lets think, Parent has more than one children. Think `CoroutineScope` is a parent and this parent can have more than one child which are also coroutines. These childrens are known as `job`

```
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope()
    coroutineScope(IO).launch{
    val childOne = launch(Main){}
   val childTwo = launch(Main){}
}
```

see that childOne and childTwo? why we need these? because we can't directly cancel the coroutine there is no such way the coroutine can be cancelled directly, either the coroutine gets completed or it gets failed. But what if we wanna cancel it? in such cases we need `job`. But thing to be notice here these job `children` are totally associated with parent. And Parent is (IO) and childrens are (Main), this parent is started in IO Disptacher but when it comes to those childrens they are gonna switch to (Main) and do their thing but the parent will still be at (IO) switching the Dispatcher of childrens not gonna effect parent. 
But what happens if something wrong happens to either of the children,
in that case we will watch this summit:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0kfnydnFWI
This summit about coroutine exception and cancellation. watch it, its amazing...

**withContext:**
What is  withContext?
`withContext` should be inside any `Coroutine` or `suspend fun` because `withContext` itself is a suspending function.
`withContext` is use to switch the context in different situation
but how?

```
suspend fun fetchFromNetworkAndUpdateUI() {
    withContext(IO){
        println("Some Fake data from network")
    }
    
    withContext(Main){
        //updating Ui
        //setting that Data to some TextView etc
    }
    
}
```

see the code, we are fetching the data asynchronously from network cause we don't wanna block the `MainThread` and then we switch the context, why? cause we can't update UI related stuff in IoDispatcher that's we have change the context to `main` with `withContext(main){}` and update the UI. 
and there are other use cases like liveData, we are fetching the value using retrofit using IoDispatcher then in next step we have to set it to the liveData by using `withContext(main){}` cause we can't observe liveData's value in background thread.
yeah, I hope this helps. comment if there is any question.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Antonio Leiva article](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-coroutines/#:%7E:text=provides%20is%20withContext%20.-,withContext,the%20dispatcher%20that%20it%27s%20used.) about coroutines:

> The coroutine context is a set of rules and configurations that define
> how the coroutine will be executed

`withContext` is a function that allows you to easily change the `context` of a suspending function, in order to be sure that that function is executed in a particular thread (E.g. Thread from IO pool). To do so you can force a suspending function to execute its body within a particular thread pool, for example:

```
suspend fun getAuthenticationStatus(): AuthenticationStatus = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    when (val result = repository.getAuthenticationStatus()) {
        is Result.Success -> result.data
        is Result.Error -> AuthenticationStatus.Unauthorized
    }
}
```

This way, even if you're calling this suspending function from a UI scope (MainScope), you are 100% sure that the suspending function is executed in a worker thread and you can update the UI with the returned result in the main thread, such as:

```kotlin
MainScope().launch {
            userIdentityVM.getAuthenticationStatus().run {
                when (this) {
                    is AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated -> {
                       // do something
                    }
                    is AuthenticationStatus.Unauthorized -> {
                       // do something else
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

To sum up, by using `withContext` you can make your suspending function **"Main Safe"**.

The difference between `scope` and `context` is basically the intended purpose.
To launch a coroutine you normally use `launch` coroutine builder, defined as an extension function on `CoroutineScope`.

```kotlin
fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    // ...
): Job
```

The context specified as parameter on the coroutine scope is merged to coroutine scope by plus operator and **takes precedence** on the "default" context specified by coroutine scope. This way you can execute the code in a "parent" context. To go deep I suggest you [this article](https://medium.com/@elizarov/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055) by Roman Elizarov (Team Lead for Kotlin libraries @JetBrains).