# How to make exact delay in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, delay, delayed-execution

I need to call some function after x seconds elapsed exactly.

How would I do this in Kotlin?

I've tried with using :

```
GlobalScope.launch 
{
  val seconds = 5
  val duration = (seconds * 1000).toLong()
  delay(duration)
  callTheFunction ()
}
```

but based on my measurements looks like it's sometimes accurate and sometimes not. 
Am I using it in the wrong way or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You won't be able to get it at exact intervals. How much error do you want to allow? If the function is long running, you could time how long it takes to run, then subtract that amount from the delay amount. You're still at the mercy of what's going on in your system at the time though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate 
I don't need it to be milliseconds accurate. A second of tolerance is ok, but not 5,10, or some random number of seconds. Is it possible?

Comment: Try this [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43348715/8043806) and put it inside a recursive function call.

Comment: Did you consider [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)? [You can specify the required precision](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic(long,%20long)) and [query the best offered precision](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html#getMinFlexMillis()).

Comment: How do you know it takes 5 to 10 seconds?

Comment: @GiddyNaya if you put it in the answer with a short explanation I can accept it as an answer