# How to generate 10ms timer in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to generate 10 milli second in Kotlin for my Rubik's cube solver app, how can i do that? I have a custom view which is a timer i want to update the timer in every 10 milli second

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a function after delay in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348623/how-to-call-a-function-after-delay-in-kotlin)

Comment: @marcinj no iwant to generate 10 milli second time base

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timer inline function or Timer class in java like this

```
  val timer = timer(period = 10) {
        //Do something here
    }
```

> Schedules an action to be executed periodically, starting after the
>   specified delay (expressed in milliseconds) and with the interval of
>   period milliseconds between the end of the previous task and the start
>   of the next one.

remember to cancel the timer when you are done or your activity or fragment is destroyed

> timer.cancel()

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace outputText with the thing you want to display it on

The code for the countdown:

```
val ttlTime: Long = // input the amount of ms here
        object : CountDownTimer(ttlTime, 10) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                outputText.text = "time remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 10
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                // code for what needs to happen after the countdown is finished
            }
        }.start()
```

If you want to display it proper:

```
val ttlTime: Long = // input the amount of ms here
object : CountDownTimer(ttlTime, 10) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        val microSecond = millisUntilFinished.toString().takeLast(3)
        val second = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60
        val minute = millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60) % 60
        var finalTime = microSecond

        if (second > 0) {
           finalTime = "$second $finalTime"
           if (minute > 0) {
               finalTime = "$minute $finalTime"
           }
        } else if (minute > 0) {
           finalTime = "$minute 0 $finalTime"
        }
        outputText.text = "time remaining: $finalTime"
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
       // code for what needs to happen after the countdown is finished
    }
}.start()
```

source: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/CountDownTimer

(this is in java but if you paste it in android studio you can convert it to kotlin)

If you want the timer to go up:

```
val startTiming = Calendar.getInstance()

Handler().post(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        Handler().postDelayed(this, 10)
        updateTime(startTiming)
    }
})
```

```
fun updateTime(startTime: Calendar) {
    val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance()

    val diff = currentTime.timeInMillis - startTime.timeInMillis
    val microSecond = diff.toString().takeLast(3)
    val second = (diff / 1000) % 60
    val minute = diff / (1000 * 60) % 60
    var finalTime = microSecond

    if (second > 0) {
        finalTime = "$second $finalTime"
        if (minute > 0) {
            finalTime = "$minute $finalTime"
        }
    }
    else if (minute > 0) {
        finalTime = "$minute 0 $finalTime"
    }

    outputText.text = finalTime
}
```