# Timer on SeekBar is lagging

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a simple audio player, but when i'm applying a timer to a seekbar for updating it a song starting to lag. Here's the code:

```
    final SeekBar playProgress = findViewById(R.id.playProgress);
    playProgress.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());

    //++++++++Lagging++++++++++++
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                playProgress.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            }
    },0,1000);
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    playProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int i, boolean b){
            mPlayer.seekTo(i);
        });
```

Comment: First don't use a Timer as it's full a leaks. Use a Handler. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330355/timertask-or-handler) for more information

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your timer is running every 1000 milliseconds, and changing the progress of the `playProgress` to the current position. Everytime the progress is changed (`onProgressChanged`) you are executing a `seekTo()` to the seekbar's new position, which could induce the lag.

The `onProgressChanged` signature looks like this: `onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)` - try only executing the `seekTo` method if the `fromUser` variable is `true`, which would mean that you did not set the progress programmatically (which you are doing in your timer).

Answer (score 0):

Replace:
`mPlayer.seekTo(i);`
By:
`if(b){`
`mPlayer.seekTo(i);`
`}// so that this codes executes only when the user is changing it`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it has worked for me.

> ```
> myViewHolder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
> ```

```
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                            // Update the progress depending on seek bar
                            if (fromUser) {
                                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);//if user drags the seekbar, it gets the position and updates in textView.
                            }
                            final long mMinutes = (progress / 1000) / 60;//converting into minutes
                            final int mSeconds = ((progress / 1000) % 60);//converting into seconds
                            myViewHolder.desc.setText(mMinutes + ":" + mSeconds);


                        }
```