# SeekBar - MediaPlayer lag when updating progress while playing

Tags: java, android, android-handler, android-seekbar

This question has been asked a few times, but I still could not find a answer.

I'm updating the progress on my `SeekBar` using a `Handler`, like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      mSeekBar.setProgress(mPlayer.getDuration());
      handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 2000);
    }
};

// Start the initial runnable task by posting through the handler
handler.post(runnableCode);
```

After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330355/timertask-or-handler) question.

---

The problem is that I'm experiencing lag. Every time the `SeekBar` gets update, there is a small lag.

Please note that I'm not talking about when the user 'manually' selects the `SeekBar`. I know I should check `if(fromUser)` in `onProgressChanged` when doing that.

Also, I did try a `Timer` with the same result.

Has anybody experienced this issue and how should I going about resolving this?

Comment: will be easier us to understand the exact issue if you upload any video for the problem you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Asynctask in the Background to move your SeekBar:

Asynctask : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if(MainActivity.playing) {
        int percent;
        int position = MainActivity.Player.getCurrentPosition();
        int timeRunning = MainActivity.Player.getDuration();
        if (timeRunning == 0 || position == 0) {
            percent = 0;
        } else {
            percent = (position * 100) / timeRunning;
        }

        return percent;
    }
    return -1;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    if(result  != -1){
    MainActivity.Mbar.setProgress(result);}

}
```

and then execute this task once in a secound with a timer in your Activity:

Timer:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

```
time.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new AsyncTask().execute();
        }
    },0,1000);
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: Currently you are just getting the position of the player in the background and still setting the progress in `onPostExecute`. So what you are saying is that calling `Player.getCurrentPosition();` is what is causing the lag?