# ChatApp--Adapter is not updating

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I am working on the chat app where I need to refresh the list for every one second. I am using the handler for repeated calls of that method, but it's not updating `ListView`. I am calling the notify data set changed in that method.

Messages.java

```
public class Messages extends Activity {
    ListView chatview;
    ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
    List<CBData> chatdata;
    public int APP_REFRESH_TIME_IN_SEC = 1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_details);
        chatview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatview);
        chatdata = new ArrayList<CBData>();
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getApplicationContext(), chatdata);
        chatview.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatmethod();
                handler.postDelayed(this, APP_REFRESH_TIME_IN_SEC * 1000);
            }
        }, APP_REFRESH_TIME_IN_SEC * 1000);

    }

    private void chatmethod() {
        chatdata.clear();
        String receiverid = getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiverID");
        String chaturl = Constant.URL + "chathome.php?sid=" + Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()) + "&rid=" + receiverid;
        Display.displaylog("Chat", chaturl);
        JsonObjectRequest chatreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, chaturl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray chatsarray = response.getJSONArray("chats");
                    for (int i = 0; i < chatsarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject chatobj = chatsarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        CBData cbchat = new CBData();
                        cbchat.setOwerid(chatobj.getString("sender_id"));
                        cbchat.setChatmessage(chatobj.getString("message"));
                        chatdata.add(cbchat);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Display.displaylog("ChatError", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        });
        chatreq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(500000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(chatreq);
    }
}
```

ChatAdapter.java

```
    public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<CBData> chatlist;
    Context chatcontext;
    LayoutInflater chatinflater;

    public ChatAdapter(Context chatcontext, List<CBData> chatlist) {
        this.chatcontext = chatcontext;
        this.chatlist = chatlist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return chatlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return chatlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        chatinflater = (LayoutInflater) chatcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Chatholder chatholder;
        final CBData chatdatalist = chatlist.get(position);
        String owerid = Session.getUserID(chatcontext);
        if (convertView == null) {
            chatholder=new Chatholder();
            final boolean isMe = chatdatalist.getOwerid().equals(owerid);
            if (isMe) {
                convertView = chatinflater.inflate(R.layout.chatright, parent, false);
                chatholder.chatbubble = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chatbubble);
                convertView.setTag(chatholder);
            } else {
                convertView = chatinflater.inflate(R.layout.chatleft, parent, false);
                chatholder.chatbubble = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chatbubble);
                convertView.setTag(chatholder);
            }
        }else {
            chatholder= (Chatholder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        chatholder.chatbubble.setText(chatdatalist.getChatmessage());
//        TextView chatbubble = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chatbubble);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class Chatholder {
        TextView chatbubble;
    }
}
```

Updated Message.java

```
public class Messages extends Activity {
    ListView chatview;
    ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
    List<CBData> chatdata;
    public int APP_REFRESH_TIME_IN_SEC = 1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_details);
        chatview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatview);
        chatdata = new ArrayList<CBData>();
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getApplicationContext(), chatdata);
        chatview.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatmethod();
                handler.postDelayed(this, APP_REFRESH_TIME_IN_SEC * 1000);
            }
        }, APP_REFRESH_TIME_IN_SEC * 1000);

    }

    private void chatmethod() {
        chatdata = new ArrayList<CBData>();
        String receiverid = getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiverID");
        String chaturl = Constant.URL + "chathome.php?sid=" + Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()) + "&rid=" + receiverid;
        Display.displaylog("Chat", chaturl);
        JsonObjectRequest chatreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, chaturl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray chatsarray = response.getJSONArray("chats");
                    for (int i = 0; i < chatsarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject chatobj = chatsarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        CBData cbchat = new CBData();
                        cbchat.setOwerid(chatobj.getString("sender_id"));
                        cbchat.setChatmessage(chatobj.getString("message"));
                        chatdata.add(cbchat);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getApplicationContext(), chatdata); 
                chatview.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Display.displaylog("ChatError", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        });
        chatreq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(500000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(chatreq);
    }
}
```

ChatDetail.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/chatview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ChatLeft.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/chatbubble"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bg"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ChatRight.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/chatbubble"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bg"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you sure that repeatedly calling handler  ?

Comment: yes for every one second final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatmethod();
                handler.postDelayed(this, APP_REFRESH_TIME_IN_SEC * 1000);
            }
        }, APP_REFRESH_TIME_IN_SEC * 1000);

Comment: logcat also showing repeated call of the url

Comment: tried that but no change just repeating the same data 'n' number of times

Comment: After uninstalling and re-installing the app then only updated data is coming in it

Comment: no its not working sir

Comment: yes method is calling but there is no change in the data

Comment: chatdata = new ArrayList<CBData>();try {JSONArray chatsarray = response.getJSONArray("chats"); for (int i = 0; i < chatsarray.length(); i++) {JSONObject chatobj = chatsarray.getJSONObject(i);CBData cbchat = new CBData();cbchat.setOwerid(chatobj.getString("sender_id"));
cbchat.setChatmessage(chatobj.getString("message"));
chatdata.add(cbchat);
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getApplicationContext(), chatdata); chatview.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

Comment: like this  i am doing sir

Comment: Sir please once check my adapter is  i am using correctly or not

Comment: updated the code Sir please go through it

Comment: check with increasing time intervell with 5 second

Comment: once please check the webservice i think data is reading till the chat id 20 after that inflater error is giving null in the debugging sir

Comment: increased the time interval sir but no change

Comment: once i had uninsatalled and re-installed the app the complete data is coming sir

Comment: please help sir not able to understand what is the error

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 ((BaseAdapter) chatview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: if use the like that it says that cant resolve method notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: After uninstalling and re-installing the app then only updated data is coming in it

Comment: please help sir not able to understand what is the error

Answer (score 0):

Inside ChatAdapter add the folllowing code

```
public void reload(List<CBData> chatlist) {
        this.chatlist=chatlist;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Replace `chatdata.clear();` to  `chatdata = new ArrayList<CBData>();`

Replace `chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to

```
chatAdapter.reload(chatdata);
```

Comment: Place log or do debug to find whether any of the above functions are called and also check data from the webservice

Comment: yes sir its getting called i also checked the webservice data is coming in it

Comment: Sir please once check my adapter is i am using correctly or not

Comment: After uninstalling and re-installing the app then only updated data is coming in it

Comment: Use debugging to find whether chatAdapter.reload(chatdata); is called repeatedly .... if not then ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353689/how-to-repeat-a-task-after-a-fixed-amount-of-time-in-android

Comment: sir its only reading till the half the webservice after that its not reasding giving the null in place inflater sir till the chat id 20 sir please once check the webservice sir

Comment: once i had uninsatalled and re-installed the app the complete data is coming sir

Comment: please help sir not able to understand what is the error