# How to Leak a Context. Can an instance of MyHandler cause leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, handler, weak-references

I read the article [How to Leak a Context: Handlers & Inner Classes](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html), and now I have got a question. If I pass `mHandler` as a parameter to another thread to send messages from that thread to the main thread, will it cause memory leaks?

**SampleActivity**

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Instances of static inner classes do not hold an implicit reference to
     * their outer class.
     */
    private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<SampleActivity> mActivity;

        public MyHandler(SampleActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<SampleActivity>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            SampleActivity activity = mActivity.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private final MyHandler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Run a thread (authentication, synchronization, etc.)
        // Later the user might press the Home button, the Back button, or make a call
        new MyThread(mHandler).start();
    }
}
```

**MyThread**

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private final Handler handler;

    public MyThread(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // A long operation

        // I'm done
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: this link may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278875/handlers-and-memory-leaks-in-android#11336822

Comment: @fada21, no. That's what I started with. The only one difference between my question and the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278875/handlers-and-memory-leaks-in-android#11336822 it that they use a fragment instead of an activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If MyThread is a static or external class, it can't cause leaks. There is no any non-weak references  to activity.

Answer (score 2):

It looks ok. I don't see any object holding link to Activity (WeakRef is ok as it can be GCed).  I don't see potential leaks here ;)

Comment: I was not right, my mistake, sorry :) WeakRef + static seems ok, only MyThread and MyHdandler are unreachable for GC.