# Using a Static Handler to update the UI thread

Tags: android, user-interface, memory-leaks, handler, android-handler

When using a background thread to do work, typically you'd update the UI through a Handler.

One way to do this was defining a handler at the class level as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685768/3363126), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5185155/3363126)

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(){
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    //update UI or call class methods here
  }
};
```

However, this construct would result in the following warning

```
Handler class should be static otherwise memory leaks might occur
```

Another way to do this was to use a static inner class as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11408340/3363126), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336822/3363126)

```
static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<Type> myWeakReference; 

    MyHandler(Type reference) {
        myWeakReference = new WeakReference<Type>(reference);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
       //Update UI or call class methods here using weak reference
    }
}
```

However, this form of constructor has been Deprecated according to the Android docs.

public Handler ()

> This constructor is deprecated. Implicitly choosing a Looper during
> Handler construction can lead to bugs where operations are silently
> lost (if the Handler is not expecting new tasks and quits), crashes
> (if a handler is sometimes created on a thread without a Looper
> active), or race conditions, where the thread a handler is associated
> with is not what the author anticipated. Instead, use an Executor or
> specify the Looper explicitly, using Looper#getMainLooper, {link
> android.view.View#getHandler}, or similar. If the implicit thread
> local behavior is required for compatibility, use new
> Handler(Looper.myLooper()) to make it clear to readers.

How should updating the UI from a Handler be done currently, and should a Handler still be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated the docs, it says to use `Looper.getMainLooper()`, just change your code to:

```
MyHandler(Type reference) {
    super(Looper.getMainLooper());
    myWeakReference = new WeakReference<Type>(reference);
}
```

to update the UI from the main/UI thread.

Comment: I accepted this because it is working for me. But I'm not clear on why it is okay to use the Deprecated constructor, even if you are calling the superclass method through it.