# android - How to repeat a function every contant time?

Tags: android, repeat

How to schedule a function every defined time with the option to change this time?
I found that I can do it using timer & timerTask or handler. The problem that it dosen't repeats the time I defined, it repeats randomaly...

```
    runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //some action
            handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
        }
    };

            int hours = settings.getIntervalHours();
            int minutes = settings.getIntervalMinutes();

            long interval = (hours * 60 + minutes) * 60000;

            changeTimerPeriod(interval);

private void changeTimerPeriod(long period) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    interval = period;
    runnable.run();
}
```

Comment: You can use Handler. You might get your precise solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6242292/6155248)

Answer (score 12):

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) object in the `onCreate` method. Its `postDelayed` method causes the `Runnable` parameter to be added to the message queue and to be run after the specified amount of time elapses (that is 0 in given example). Then this will queue itself after fixed rate of time (1000 millis in this example).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    android.os.Handler customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //write here whaterver you want to repeat
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: @MarkBuikema where is the leak? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Memory leak may be the wrong term, but this will continue when the application is paused (which I assume is not what you want).

Answer (score 3):

I used the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242292/6155248)

But in the code where the handler was initialized,  I used

```
mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper);
```

instead of

```
mHandler = new Handler();
```

which worked for me