# How to stop Handler in Android

Tags: android, handler, runnable

In my application I have created a calendar with Gridview and in that Gridview I am displaying dates and some availability of events with the help of Imageview and to do this I have created a handler.

Now I want to stop the handler.

**MainActivity.java**

```
// inside oncreate

Handler handler = new Handler();
refreshCalendar();

// outside oncreate

public void refreshCalendar() { 
    calAdapter.refreshDays();
    calAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    handler.post(calendarUpdater);
    calTitle.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", cal));
}
public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        items.clear();
        allData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        allData.clear();
        allData = db.showAllEvents();

        String currentDate = (String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM/yyyy", cal);
        for(int i=0; i<allData.size(); i++)
        {
            String date[] = allData.get(i).get("date").split("/");
            String md[] = currentDate.split("/");
            if(date[1].equals(md[0]) && date[2].equals(md[1]))
            {
                items.add(date[0]);
                System.out.println("dates: "+date[0]);
            }
        }
        calAdapter.setItems(items);
        calAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Please tell me how and where I should disable this thread.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this to stop that runnable

```
handler.removeCallbacks(calendarUpdater);
```

**removeCallbacks(Runnable r)** :Remove any pending posts of `Runnable r` that are in the message queue.

**Edit**

You can organize your code like this

In your `onCreate()` of `MainActivity.java`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
refreshCalendar()

//outside  oncreate 

public void refreshCalendar() { 
    calAdapter.refreshDays();
    calAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    startRepeatingTask();
    calTitle.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", cal));
}

public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        items.clear();
        allData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        allData.clear();
        allData = db.showAllEvents();

        String currentDate = (String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM/yyyy", cal);
        for(int i=0; i<allData.size(); i++)
        {
            String date[] = allData.get(i).get("date").split("/");
            String md[] = currentDate.split("/");
            if(date[1].equals(md[0]) && date[2].equals(md[1]))
            {
                items.add(date[0]);
                System.out.println("dates: "+date[0]);
            }
        }
        calAdapter.setItems(items);
        calAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.postDelayed(calendarUpdater,5000); // 5 seconds
    }
};

void startRepeatingTask()
{
    calendarUpdater.run(); 
}

void stopRepeatingTask()
{
    handler.removeCallbacks(calendarUpdater);
}
```

Now you can just call `startRepeatingTask()` to posting message and to stop use `stopRepeatingTask()`

Inherited from following link

[Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay)

Comment: where to put this code? when i put this code after the handler.post() then it don't event start

Comment: Can I "remove" *running* `Runnable`?

Answer (score 12):

Try below line,

> handler.removeMessages(0);

Remove any pending posts of messages with code `what` that are in the message queue.

Answer (score 9):

Handler has nothing to be *stopped* or *started*. It's just a gateway to post Messages and Runnables onto thread Queue. In your case you are posting a Runnable, which will be run on Handler's thread. You have to stop that Runnable. So, put a check in that `for` loop to break it.

You can also use [`removeCallbacks(Runnable r)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) on `Handler` to cancel posted `Runnable`'s. But this won't remove those `Runnable`'s which are already running.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this `onStop()`:

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(calendarUpdater);
```

Comment: comment quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make handler a field. Then in your activity, override onStop method and stop handler call back messages like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        handler.removeCallbacks(calendarUpdater);
    }
```