# How to stop Handler in java?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to stop the handler while counting 6 seconds?
That the toast does not appear
For example, I want the handler not to work in 3 seconds and the toast not to appear, then go to the second activity in 3 seconds.
Thanks for the help friends

```
final Handler h= new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(Ab.this, "finish 6 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
},6000);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all callbacks from a Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883635/how-to-remove-all-callbacks-from-a-handler)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`.

Answer (score 0):

[How to stop Handler in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557333/how-to-stop-handler-in-android)

Though I would not use a handler for this, but more likely a `CountDownTimer`. It is easier to understand.

```
int time = 6000;

new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if(millisUntilFinished == 3000) {
            Toast.makeText(Ab.this, "finish 3 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(Ab.this, "finish 6 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}.start();
```