# How to implement retry mechanism with 100 milliseconds sleeping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I want to execute this instruction after certain milliseconds.

How can i achieve this?

```
try {
   // Get the typeface  
   MyApp.appTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplication().getAssets(),
         MyApp.fontName);
   Log.d("font","in try="+MyApp.fontName);
   Log.d("font","type face="+MyApp.appTypeFace);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Handler handler;

        handler=new Handler();
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyApp.appTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplication().getAssets(),
         MyApp.fontName);
   Log.d("font","in try="+MyApp.fontName);
   Log.d("font","type face="+MyApp.appTypeFace);

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification,100);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to post a Runnable, like so:

```
private Runnable task = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        // Execute your delayed code
    }
};
```

...

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int millisDelay = 100;
handler.postDelayed(task, millisDelay);
```

The code will execute 100 milliseconds after the `postDelayed` call.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use CountDownTimer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(100, 100) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //retry
         //restart with timer.start();
     }
  }.start();
```

But there are a lot of alternatives: AsyncTask, Threads, Runnable.

For example:

[Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay)