# How does TimerTask on Android manages threads?

Tags: android, multithreading

I was wondering how the TimerTask is working with threads.

For example, I've got a code that executes a TimerTask, which has a 'run' method which will run on the UI Thread.

```
class looper extends TimerTask {

    public looper() {

    }

    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timer.schedule(new looper(), new Date(new Date().getTime() + 100));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the timer would start like this:

```
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new looper(), new Date());
```

Will the TimerTask create a new thread? if so, how does `runOnUiThread` will work? will it move the code to the UI thread?

I've tried to eliminate the need to call the TimerTask again (`timer.schedule`) and just use an infinite loop inside the `run` to make calculations - but that would block the UI thread and the app will not respond.

P.S - I must have the code run on the UI thread, because it has to update the UI.

So, what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your questions:

- `runOnUiThread` from docs:

  > Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.
- The code at TimerTask it is executed on a different thread, so you should call `runOnUiThread` to execute code.

You are doing it right, but why are you re-creating the timertask at the run method ? Consider using `scheduleAtFixedTime` , the 100 will be the period and the delay 0.
The run method then will execute the task it is supposed to do.

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do whatever
        }
    });
```

[scheduleAtFixedTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29)

***Updated:**

If its an update to a view it is better to use `handler.postDelayed`, see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay?answertab=votes#tab-top) it will be executed after a delay on the UI thread.

Comment: I didn't post the full code, but I need to control when the next timertask will run - that's why I set the timer again.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this context-switch between the new thread and the UI thread?