# ImageButton Background doesn't change in real-time

Tags: java, android, eclipse, for-loop, imagebutton

I use this for loop to change the background of `ImageButton`:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= right_num ; i++ ){
    int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("c"+left_num+"_r"+i, "id", this.getPackageName());
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resourceId);
    imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_circle);
    sound();
}
```

I've tried `Thread sleep`, `AnimationDrawable`, `Timer` and `TimerTask`.

But it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Using an appropriate timer *will* solve the problem - but as you've only shown the version which blocks the UI thread until it's finished, we can't tell what was wrong with your timer attempt. (Don't forget you'll need to execute the code on the UI thread...) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268 for example.

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your problem? The rest of your code would be awesome as well.

Comment: please complete your answer.