# In android After button is clicked my already defined function should start running repeatedly for every 10 secs?Help me in this Please?

Tags: java, android

In my Android application I have a button. After the button is clicked my already defined function should start running repeatedly for every 10 secs? Instead of clicking button and starting the task I might call this in OnCreate() also. Help me in this Please?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to something like this:

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        myFunction();//the function to be executed
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);

myFunction(){
}
```