# How to alternate two imageview? Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Now the image is changed as soon as I click on.

I would like to make this process AUTOMATIC (ex. every second)

this is my actually code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageView:
            foto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            foto1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView2:
            foto1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            foto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can have a periodic task to do it:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        if (foto.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            foto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            foto1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            foto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            foto1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: It's better practice to use a Handler rather than a separate thread and then call runOnUiThread when dealing with timed events.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `ViewFlipper`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

You can set the delay using `setFlipInterval(int)` or in the XML using `android:flipInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Handler` with `postDelayed'. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay) for some code.

Also, you can try using 'ImageSwitcher' instead of two 'ImageView's

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean isFirstVisible;
long millis;        

while(true) {
    millis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (isFirstVisible) {
        foto1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        foto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isFirstVisible = false;
    } else {
        foto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        foto1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isFirstVisible = true;
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000 - millis % 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe use [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) (in your casae ImageSwitcher should work) and switch `View`s using `Handler`?

```
private static final int delay=1000; //ms
Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    public run(){
        //viewSwitcher.showNext();
        //exampole of swtiching
        h.postDelayed(r, delay);
    }
}
h.postDelayed(r, delay);
```

to stop this loop use `h.removeCallbacks(r)`

you may also use `viewSwitcher.postDelayed`