# Android Dev JAVA Audio Stream checking internet on loop

Tags: java, android, stream, connection

I have an audio stream playing but want to constantly check if the persons internet connection dropped- and if so- restart the audio stream or at least notify them why it stopped.

I checked the onError for mediaplayer but it doesn't get triggered when internet drops-

I have code to check for an internet connection- but is there a way to run this in the background every minute or so? (when phone goes into standby as well)

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use a [runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242292/2796939), which would be called however often you need it to.

If you want to be efficient though, I would look for an internet listener. Unfamiliar with the topic myself, but some quick searching produced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157194/2796939).

Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't a runnable stop when the phone goes into standby though?

Comment: Ah, I missed that part! Yes, it does. You will need to implement a service in that case. In that case, please have a look at this tutorial, which helped me at the time: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: yah I tried the receiver for the listener- but unfortunately that only monitors when the connection changes, not actually drops.

Comment: Gotcha- will check on that- Thank you