# Android Java: Update seekbar to show progress as audio file plays

Tags: java, android, audio, runnable

This is my first Android/Java app. I am using the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay) to try to initiate a repeating task, updating a seekbar ("timeSlider") to show progress as an audio file plays.  Here is my code (eliminating a few irrelevant lines):

```
 private int timeSliderInterval = 1000; // 1 second
 private Handler timeSliderHandler;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     Runnable doUpdateTimeSlider = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             timeSliderHandler.postDelayed(doUpdateTimeSlider, timeSliderInterval);
             updateTimeSlider();
         }
     };

     void startUpdateTimeSlider() {
         doUpdateTimeSlider.run();
     }

     void stopUpdateTimeSlider() {
         timeSliderHandler.removeCallbacks(doUpdateTimeSlider);
     }

     final SeekBar timeSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.timeSlider);

     if (timeSlider != null) {
         timeSliderHandler = new Handler();
         startUpdateTimeSlider();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         stopUpdateTimeSlider();
     }
```

The project does not display in the emulator. Tooltips show these errors:

[image]

In addition, the `startUpdateTimeSlider` and `stopUpdateTimeSlider` functions are showing this error in tooltips:

[image]

Also, in the Run window, I'm getting:

> emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
>
> emulator: ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Unknown camera factory query
>   name in ' '

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is self explained, you need to add `final` modifier.

```
final Runnable doUpdateTimeSlider = ...
```

Second one - move `startUpdateTimerSlider()` method, now its inside `onCreate()` method

Looks like you missed `}`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Runnable doUpdateTimeSlider = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         timeSliderHandler.postDelayed(doUpdateTimeSlider, timeSliderInterval);
         updateTimeSlider();
     }
 };
}//<--------HERE

 void startUpdateTimeSlider() {
     doUpdateTimeSlider.run();
 }
```

Comment: You pinpointed the problems reflected in these errors.  Thank you!  I'm not totally out of the woods yet, unfortunately. I've created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414330/android-java-cannot-resolve-in-postdelayed

Comment: First comment of the new question is a correct answer