# Android update ProgressBar with Handler

Tags: android, handler, android-progressbar

I would like to update the progressBar with Handler and for loop but without success.

### Code:

```
public void increase_splash_bar (int from, int to)
{
    Handler handler1 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); 
    for (progress_k = from; progress_k<=to ;progress_k++) 
    {
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
        {
             @Override
             public void run() 
             {
                  FrontLayout.update_splash_progress_bar(progress_k, 100);
             }
        }, 2000);
    } 
}
```

### Question:

The progress bar increase immediately to the end value instead of progressively.
Why?

Comment: You can update progress bar continuously with a handler. Why do you need a for loop for?

Comment: could you please advise explicitly? Or base on code above, why it does not work properly for increasing the progressbar gradually, but directly jump to the end value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

**Solution 1**

```
public void increase_splash_bar (int from, int to)
{
    Handler handler1 = new Handler(); 
    class Task implements Runnable {

        int start,end;

        Task(int a,int b) { start = a; end = b;}

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i =start ; i <= end; i++) {
                final int value = i;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler1.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(value);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    Thread t = new Thread(new Task(from, to));   //call it
    t.start();

}
```

**Solution 2: More Simple**

If thread is too much to ask for this problem..

you can use the following solution to use a single `Handler` to update progressbar:

**code**

```
 public class HandlerDemo extends Activity
{
  ProgressBar bar;
  Handler handler = new Handler()
  {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
      bar.incrementProgressBy(5);
    }
  };
  boolean isRunning = false;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
  {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
  }

  public void onStart()
  {
    super.onStart();
    bar.setProgress(0);

    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < 20 && isRunning; i++)
          {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
          }
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
          // just end the background thread
        }
      }
    });

    isRunning = true;
    background.start();
  }

  public void onStop()
  {
    super.onStop();
    isRunning = false;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: a new `Thread`? for making such a simple animation? it seems you dont know what you can do with simple `Handler`

Comment: sure i do know...i am open to take any suggestion.There are many ways to solve a `SIMPLE` problem

Comment: and the best one is to use simplest solutions and not to use a cannon to kill a fly - *"Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler"*

Comment: i get it ...thankx i will look into other simple ways to solve the problem.

Comment: i have edited the answer...*Stop downVoting the answer without a valid Reason* add a comment what is the problem!

Comment: you are still using a `new Thread`, this is NOT a solution for any animation on android platform, see "delayed" methods of a `Handler` instead or for example Joel Duggan's answer here

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public void increase_splash_bar (int from, int to)
{
    Handler handler1 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); 
    for (progress_k = from; progress_k<=to ;progress_k++) 
    {
        final int curr_progress_k = progress_k;
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                 FrontLayout.update_splash_progress_bar(curr_progress_k, 100);
            }
        }, progress_k * 100);      // adjust "100" value to adjust speed
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yet changing to this progress_k * 100 still cannot fix the problem that the value directly jumping to end immediately?

Comment: its not gonna work, your `Runnable`s will be delaeyd but still the value passed to `update_splash_progress_bar` method will be equal to `to + 1` (it will not be `from, from + 1, from + 2, ... , to`)

Comment: @pearmak simply use `Message`s (and override `Handler#handleMessage`), not `Runnable`s

Comment: @pearmak or if you really, really need `Runnable` add a field like this in your `Runnable`: `int field_progress_k = progress_k;` and use that `field_progress_k` field

Comment: @pearmak I updated the answer to fix the problem you stated. The `final int curr_progress_k` is important, and I forgot about it.

Comment: yes, this is what i stated in my prev comment but the right way is either to use not anonymous `Runnable` (but rther a class that extends `Runnable` and pass current loop index to the constructor) or (what i would do) use `Message`s and custom `Handler` class

Comment: yes, worse and better, the way OP want to do that is among the former

Answer (score 3):

[Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay) 
@inazaruk

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Handler mHandler;
private int progressInt = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    runnable.run();

}


Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            updateProgress();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        } finally {
            mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, progressInt);
        }
    }
};

private void updateProgress() {
    progressInt += 1;
    if (progressInt > 100) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    } else {
        progressBar.setProgress(progressInt);
    }
}
```