# How to check and set network status in TextView every 2 seconds?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-thread

I want to set network status in TextView, which I want to repetitively call method and set in background, so I used AsyncTask class with infinite loop

```
class setNetworkText extends AsyncTask
{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        for(;;)
        {
            if(isNetworkConnected()) //check internet connection and if found it return true
                setOnline();         // it set my TextView text to Online
            else
                setOffline();        // it set my TextView text to Offline

            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

but it is not working, it stops my application.

Comment: Can you tell me why you want to check it every 2 secs, because its a heavy task and will drain too much battery. If i can understand your purpose to do so I can help you with another solution.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay

Comment: I want to set my **TextView** text to show that I am online or not .. and I want to check it in every 2secs bcoz i think it is enough to call check method in 2 sec instead of calling it in every small millisecond..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //check something on time interval here 1 second  
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //when your task done here 3 second is time to end 
     }
  }.start();
```

explanation
**CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)**

**millisInfuture** will be how long you want to run the task and **countDownInterval** is the interval in your case it is 2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Android will (in most versions) only execute one AsyncTask at a time - so if you keep blocking in `doInBackground` of one AsyncTask, no other AsyncTasks will run, thus blocking your application.

Take a look at using `Handler.postDelayed` or using a TimerTask. They are more suited for repeating actions.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use AsyncTask to do that. You should use Handler to schedule a task periodically.

```
// Create the Handler
Handler handler = new Handler();

// Define the code block to be executed
private Runnable runnableTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if(isNetworkConnected())
            setOnline(); 
        else
            setOffline();         
    }
};

// Call on main thread (for example, inside onResume())
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.postDelayed(runnableTask, 2000);
}
// Remember to unregister it onPause()
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnableTask);
}
```