# I want timer/handler or something else to run some specific function twice?

Tags: java, android

When I start the app "specific function" needs to be executed.

After 10 seconds "specific function" needs to be triggered again.

After this second operation "specific function" should not triggered again.

Comment: see `android.os.Handler` API then

Comment: Please help me with the code as I am new to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way to handle your problem.

1. If there is any condition you want to check and accordingly do the work after every 10 seconds You should Use a `Handler`.
2. If there is no condition on anything and you just want to run the code after every 10 Seconds. Then `TimerTask` is also one way. I have actually worked with `TimerTask` class. So i say it is quite easy.

Creating your `class` and implementing the `methods`.

```
class myTaskTimer extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("TAG", "run: "+"timer x");
        }
    }
```

and now in your code Create a new `Timer` Object and `initialize` it.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
```

Now you can schedule your task in it after a specified interval like below:

```
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new myTaskTimer(),10000,10000);
```

The function is explained below:

> void scheduleAtFixedRate (TimerTask task, 
>                   long delay, 
>                   long period)
>
> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution,
>   beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place
>   at approximately regular intervals, separated by the specified period.

and now for `handler` , below is the code and it can check for any condition. Code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242292/6761707) for your help.

```
private int mInterval = 10000; // 10 seconds as you need
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

    // your code here

    mHandler = new Handler();
    startRepeatingTask();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopRepeatingTask();
}

Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
          try {
               updateStatus(); //this function can change value of mInterval.
          } finally {
               // 100% guarantee that this always happens, even if
               // your update method throws an exception
               mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
          }
    }
};

void startRepeatingTask() {
    mStatusChecker.run(); 
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use android.os.Handler as per @pskink comment.

```
private void callSomeMethodTwice(){
    context.myMethod(); //calling 1st time
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            context.myMethod(); //calling 2nd time after 10 sec
        }
    },10000};
}
```