# Android: Use timer to perform a task periodically

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, slider, repeat

I am currently working on an android music app which needs to call an api to get the link of album-art and put it in slider, after 'x' seconds I have to call another api and get an url of advertisement and load it on slider. And then after 'y' seconds I have to repeat the whole process.

What is the best way to implement it without having memory leakage issue. I am currently using 'https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider' this slider.

To be more specific, let's say I have two functions, I need to call both periodically after '12' and '3' seconds, how can I implement it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay

Comment: helped me understanding my solution, I needed two timer and used flip-flop methodology to solve my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this by using `postDelayed()`

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed (() -> {
//your code here
}, DELAY_TIME);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I needed two timer and used flip-flop methodology to solve my situation.