# CountDown Timer not working properly while scrolling?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

`CountDownTimer` is not showing while scrolling

Below is my code;

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
{

   if (holder.timer != null) {
        holder.timer.cancel();
    }



  if (!resturantDetails.getRemainingTime().equalsIgnoreCase("") && holder.timer == null) {

            Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "" + resturantDetails.getRemainingTime());
            holder.timer = new CountDownTimer(Long.parseLong(resturantDetails.getRemainingTime()), 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    long seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                    long minutes = ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                    long hours = ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

                    holder.tvHour.setText(String.format("%02d", hours));
                    holder.tvMinutes.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes));
                    holder.tvSeconds.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds));
                }

                @Override

                public void onFinish() {

                }
            }.start();
        } 
}
```

Below is my `ViewHolder` class;

```
  public class ResturantDashboardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        CountDownTimer timer;

        public ResturantDashboardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `RecyclerView` recycles the view on scroll... that's why `onBindViewHolder` only called when view is visible ... after that view is recycled so it's bad practice to initialize `CountDownTimer `in `onBindViewHolder` that will be initialize again and again

Comment: Can you please give me example...I will upvote your answer...plz help me

Comment: provide the code you want to execute in `CountDownTimer`

Comment: Hii @Hanzala plz show my edited code and give me best solution for this

Comment: you want to show Remaining Time  of something in every item in recyclerView right?

Comment: Yupp @Hanzala... Not every item but which time has remaining time flag from api in that item only...bt it not working while scrolling

Comment: initialize `CountDownTimer` in your activity and add it's reference to adapter so calculate remaining time in `onBindViewHolder` and only call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onTick()` method

Comment: Can you give me example for this so that I can upvote your answer @Hanzala

Comment: off the topic, don't use countdown timer as it is never 100% accurate, go for handler

Comment: Can you tell what can use for showing timer on behalf of CountDownTimer in Recyclerview @notTdar

Comment: use a handler with runnables

Comment: Can you give me solution as in the form of answer @notTdar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got best solution;

Below is adapter code for count down timer

```
    public class RestaurantListDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantListDetailAdapter.ResturantDashboardViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    ArrayList<RestaurantListDetail.DataModel.ResultList> resturantList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context mContext;
    Utils utils;
    String latitude, longitude;
    OffersAdapter offersAdapter;
    private ArrayList<RestaurantListDetail.DataModel.ResultList> mFilteredList;

    public RestaurantListDetailAdapter(ArrayList res, Context mContext, String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.resturantList = res;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;

        long maxTime = 0;
        for (RestaurantListDetail.DataModel.ResultList item : resturantList) {
            if (!item.getRemainingTime().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                maxTime = Long.parseLong(item.getRemainingTime());
            }
        }

        new CountDownTimer(maxTime, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {

                for (int i = 0, dataLength = resturantList.size(); i < dataLength; i++) {
                    RestaurantListDetail.DataModel.ResultList item = resturantList.get(i);
                    if (!item.getRemainingTime().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        item.setRemainingTime(String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(item.getRemainingTime())-1000)) ;
                    }
                }

                //remove the expired items
                //Iterator<RestaurantListDetail.DataModel.ResultList> dataIterator = resturantList.iterator();
                //while (dataIterator.hasNext()) {
                //RestaurantListDetail.DataModel.ResultList rd = dataIterator.next();
                //if (rd.getRemainingTime().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                //          dataIterator.remove();
                //                        }
                //                    }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            // resturantList.clear();
            // notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.start();

    }

    @Override
    public ResturantDashboardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dashboard_search_item, parent, false);
        ResturantDashboardViewHolder viewHolder = new ResturantDashboardViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ResturantDashboardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final RestaurantListDetail.DataModel.ResultList resturantDetails = resturantList.get(position);

        if (!resturantDetails.getRemainingTime().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            long seconds = Long.parseLong(resturantDetails.getRemainingTime()) / 1000;
            long minutes = seconds / 60;

            holder.tvHour   .setText(String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(Long.parseLong(resturantDetails.getRemainingTime()))));
            holder.tvMinutes.setText(String.format("%02d",minutes % 60));
            holder.tvSeconds.setText(String.format("%02d",seconds % 60));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resturantList.size();
    }


    public class ResturantDashboardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        LinearLayout llBookingTable, ll_timer_slot, llOfferLayout, llOffers, rl_offer;
        TextView tv_resturantname, tvSeatLeft, tvListsTags, tvOffers, textView, tvHour, tvMinutes, tvSeconds, tvOutlets, tv_distance, tv_place, tv_rating, tvClosed, tvCostForTwo, tvOffer, tvSuburb;


        public ResturantDashboardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvOffers = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOffers);
            rl_offer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_offer);
            tvSeatLeft = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSeatLeft);
            tvListsTags = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvListsTags);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            llOfferLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llOfferLayout);

            llBookingTable = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llBookingTable);
            ll_timer_slot = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_timer_slot);
            tvHour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHour);
            tvMinutes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
            tvSeconds = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
            tvOutlets = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOutlets);
            llOffers = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llOffers);
            tvSuburb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSuburb);
            tv_distance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_distance);
            tv_place = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_resturant_place);
            tv_resturantname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_resturant_item);
            tv_rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rating);
            tvClosed = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClosed);
            tvCostForTwo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCostForTwo);
            tvOffer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOffer);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is simple.

`RecyclerView` reuses the holders, calling bind each time to update the data in them.

Since you create a `CountDownTimer` each time any data is bound, you will end up with multiple timers updating the same `ViewHolder`.

The best thing here would be to `cancel` it before binding the data (if started) and rescheduling to the desired duration.

> ```
> public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
>     ...
>     if (holder.timer != null) {
>         holder.timer.cancel();
>     }
>     holder.timer = new CountDownTimer(expiryTime, 500) {
>         ...
>     }.start();
> }
>
> public static class ResturantDashboardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
>     ...
>     CountDownTimer timer;
>
>     public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

This way you will cancel any current timer instance for that `ViewHolder` prior to starting another timer.

Comment: @VishalVaishnav try this!

Comment: Sure...wait I am checking this

Comment: I tried this code...but this is only start counter when visible item in recyclerview... it does not start timer by default at loading recyclerview