# Checking Room DB table every seconds in Background and display Notification

Tags: android, notifications, background, schedule

I am building a scheduling App, I store all scheduled notification inside a Room DB Table, I want to check every second if the current time/date is equal to the DB Table time/date, and it's should display a notification for it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using LivaData?

Comment: LiveData wont help for this

Comment: Hi , please consider upvoting my answer, i'm trying to get rid of all my zero rated answers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { //DB action here 
        //Todo, here you would put in your DB logic to check if the stuff matches
         handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Comment: Am really busy with something else, I just implement it yesterday and it works, but sometimes it works when I minimize the app and also close the entire app. what can I do to achieve this. And also how can I pause it and let it continue when it performed something.

Comment: you would have to look into creating a service for something like that @Harbdollar

Comment: Yea, I know about service, That means I have to add it inside a service,

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this SO question here : [Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay) have a look at `Handler's` `postDelayed` feature. get the value from the database you want to check and then use a postDelayed to check if it matches up

Comment: Can you please help me design code because am not getting it, and am been divert to WorkManager and am still confused.

Comment: I submitted a different answer now, have a look at that @Harbdollar

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use another design pattern to implement it instead of "check every second", but here is a little snippet how it could work:

```
final LiveData<Integer> id = scheduledRepository.getScheduledItemId(System.currentTimeMillis());
        id.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                if(integer == null){
                    //do nothing
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), YOUR_NOTIFICATION_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    id.removeObserver(this);
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

Your DAO will be something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM T_SCHEDULER WHERE date = :currentdate")
 LiveData<Integer> getScheduledItemId(long currentdate);
```

Comment: Will I implement this inside a button or what?, because I think the code should be inside a service or background?

Comment: try to put it in a handler like this:

`Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //DB action here
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);`